# Toggling button image in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to toggle an icon in a button in react but I've tried everything and nothing works. I can change the background/text color toggling onClick but I'm missing something to change the icon and I don't know what! Any help?

Here's my code:
App.js

```
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import { useState } from "react";
import Layout from "./layout";
import ThemeContext, { themes } from "./theme-context";
import { faSun, faMoon } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'

function App() {

  const sun = <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faSun} />
  const moon = <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faMoon} />

  const [theme, setTheme] = useState(themes.dark)


  const toggleTheme = () => theme === themes.dark ? setTheme(themes.light) : setTheme(themes.dark)


  return (
    <ThemeContext.Provider value={theme}>
      <button onClick={toggleTheme}>


        {sun}



      </button>
      <Layout />
    </ThemeContext.Provider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

theme-context.js

```
import React from "react"


export const themes = {
    dark: {
        color: "white",
        background: "black",
        padding: "5px",
        width: "200px",
        textAlign: "center",
    },
    light: {
        color: "black",
        background: "white",
        padding: "5px",
        width: "200px",
        textAlign: "center",


    }

}

const ThemeContext = React.createContext(themes.dark)

export default ThemeContext;
```

layout.jsx

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import ThemeContext from "./theme-context";

const Layout = () =>{

const theme = useContext(ThemeContext)
return (
    <div style={theme} >
<p>This is your content</p>
</div>
)
}

export default Layout;
```

I have tried {themes.dark? : {sun} ? {moon}} but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `{themes.dark? : {sun} ? {moon}}` was very close to correct (concept-wise, the syntax is not correct though). What you needed to do instead is `{ theme === themes.dark ? sun : moon }` With your original snippet, you were just checking to see if `themes.dark` was [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy), which will always return true because it is an object. What you needed to do was check to see if the current theme was the same as `themes.dark`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: note that there are no brackets around the sun and moon variables because they are already components and in an interpolation block. Wrapping them un that way simply replaces them with an object that contains a key that is either `sun` or `moon` that has the value of the comonent.

Comment: I OWN YOU MY SOUL. Thank you for being so kind and explaining so well!! I got it now!

Comment: No problem. Just please mark this as the answer so that others can benefit from it as well!